# Spurious wakeup with atomics and condition_variables

Tags: c++, atomic, wait, notify, condition-variable

`std::atomic<T>` and `std::condition_variable` both have member `wait` and `notify_one` functions. In some applications, programmers may have a choice between using either for synchronization purposes. One goal with these `wait` functions is that they should coordinate with the operating system to minimize spurious wakeups. That is, the operating system should avoid waking the `wait`-ing thread until `notify_one` or `notify_all` are called.

On my machine, `sizeof(std::atomic<T>)` is `sizeof(T)` and `sizeof(std::condition_variable)` is 72. If you exclude `std::atomic<T>`'s `T` member, then `std::condition_variable` reserves 72 bytes for to serve its synchronization purposes while `sizeof(std::atomic<T>)` reserves 0 bytes.

My question: should I expect different behavior between `std::condition_variable`'s and `std::atomic<T>`'s `wait` functions? For example, should `std::condition_variable` have fewer spurious wakeups?

[`std::atomic<T>::wait()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/wait)

[`std::atomic<T>::notify_one()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/notify_one)

[`std::condition_variable::wait()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait)

[`std::condition_variable::notify_one()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_one)

Comment: `condition_variable` would take mutex with every wake to check wait condition, and release it when going back to wait. Locking/Releasing mutex is a service call to OS (well depends on implementation but usually is). I expect that 'atomic' would not need such guard to check wait condition. So 'atomic' does not need thread switching to acquire mutex at all.

Comment: If the thread that calls wait doesn't check that the atomic variable changed, what thread does?

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't check that the atomic variable changed" ? whole point of wait is to check variable changed

Comment: You said: "So 'atomic' does not need thread switching to acquire mutex at all." I understood this as: "You might think that when atomic checks if its ```T``` changed, your processor need to switch to the calling thread. However, since 'atomic would not need such guard to check wait condition', switching threads in unnecessary. Another thread can check whether or not the atomic's ```T``` changed, and if it has, THEN wake the calling thread." This makes sense to me. I assume then that some OS process is in charge of checking if atomic's ```T``` changed (for ALL atomics currently waiting).

Comment: Yeap, bad wording... Let me correct myself then. `cv.wait()` releases mutex when going to sleep and locking it again when wakes up because of notification. If mutex is locked by other thread, thread holding `cv` would go to sleep once again until mutex is released by other thread. Once `cv` acquire mutex after all, it could check wait condition. Atomic does not need mutex and potentially could cause lesser thread context switching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question: should I expect different behavior between `std::condition_variable`'s and `std::atomic<T>`'s `wait` functions? For example, should `std::condition_variable` have fewer spurious wakeups?

`std::atomic::wait` does not have spurious wake ups. The standard guarantees that a changed value was observed, it says in [[atomics.types.generic.general]/30](https://eel.is/c++draft/atomics.types.generic#atomics.types.operations-30):

> Effects: Repeatedly performs the following steps, in order:
>
> (30.1)
> Evaluates load(order) and compares its value representation for equality against that of old.
>
> (30.2)
> If they compare unequal, returns.
>
> (30.3)
> Blocks until it is unblocked by an atomic notifying operation or is unblocked spuriously.

So, **if the underlying implementation of atomic wait makes spurious wake ups, they are hidden by the C++ standard library implementation**.

If your questions is about whether there are more or fewer spurious wakeups in **the underlying implementation of** atomics or condition variables, then it is implementation specific. Will depend on operating system and library implementation. Most likely answer is: **no, because the ultimate implementation, where OS makes kernel call is highly likely the same.**

Comment: thanks, yes I guess I skipped over that it repeats.